# Openlayers 3: Select a feature programmatically

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to upgrade my system from Openlayers 2 to Openlayers 3 and I have having one particular issue that I cannot seem to figure out.

My application has a grid and a map and when a user clicks on the grid I want to select the relevant point on the map.

In Openlayers 2 I used the following:

```
self.selectControl.select(feature[0]);
```

I cannot find or understand how to do the same in Openlayers 3.

So to be clear, I have a feature which I have found programmatically and I want to select that feature on a map (programmatically)!

I cannot seem to find anything in the APIs but that might be due to my lack of understanding as I am new to Openlayers.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To do this you need to do the following:

```
mySelectControl.getFeatures().clear() -> removes the selected items

mySelectControl.getFeatures().push(featureToSelect) -> selects the applied feature
```

Comment: @bebraw - I will when StackOverflow will let me, says I have to wait another hour (from time of writing)

Comment: Thanks for that. It's far from obvious in any of the official documentation or any of the examples I've found, that you can `push()` to the `getFeatures()` array. _[Yeah, I know, it's inherent in the definition of `ol.Collection`, but that's only obvious in hindsight]_

Answer (score 11):

```
var selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select(}); 
map.addInteraction(selectInteraction);

function highlightFeature(feat){
   selectInteraction.getFeatures().push(feat);
   selectInteraction.dispatchEvent({
      type: 'select',
      selected: [feat],
      deselected: []
   });
}
```

works like a char on latest openlayers 4.5

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a select interaction to your map.

   ```
   var selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select();
   map.addInteraction(selectInteraction);
   ```
2. Add any features you want to select to the select interaction's feature array.

   ```
   selectInteractions.getFeatures().push(featureToSelect);
   ```