# Openlayers 4.11 : no style applied when programatically selecting a feature

Tags: openlayers

I'm using the accepted answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319705/openlayers-3-how-to-select-a-feature-programmatically-using-ol-interaction-sele%20here) to programatically select a feature on my map.

*All ok, except that my custom select style is not applied (the element looks just like before).*

I'm using this code to setup my `Select` interaction:

```
var selectSingleOrDoubleClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
    style: this.selectCustomStyle,
    condition: function(mapBrowserEvent) {
        return ol.events.condition.singleClick(mapBrowserEvent) || ol.events.condition.doubleClick(mapBrowserEvent);
    },
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
        ...
    }
});
```

I'm doing this in order to programmatically select my feature:

```
selectSingleOrDoubleClick.getFeatures().clear();
selectSingleOrDoubleClick.getFeatures().push(featureToSelect);

selectControl.dispatchEvent({
    type: 'select',
    selected: [featureToSelect],
    deselected: []
});
```

I should not that my feature IS `considered` selected (for example if I select another feature via user interaction, my previously-selected feature becomes unselected, etc.

Comment: Is possible to create a sample Jsfiddle or anywhere.. where we can reproduce the same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is normal behavior in Openlayers, whenever the Features involved in your selection already have a *non-default style applied*.

So if you want to fix this, then you need to use `select/unselect` events to apply whatever style you need to have applied, and remove it as necessary.