# Programmatically trigger a select event in open layers 4

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, gwt-openlayers

Is there any chance to trigger a manual selection for an ol.feature in ol4? I saw the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319705/openlayers-3-how-to-select-a-feature-programmatically-using-ol-interaction-sele), but i have the same issue : the custom selection style is not applied. Any workarounds to get programmatically selection working as normal selection(within map)?

Comment: I suspect it's a bug in openlayers 4; I have spent several hours on the same issue (which I described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44264227/openlayers-4-11-no-style-applied-when-programatically-selecting-a-feature ), but still nothing to show for it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had to solve was - if an user clicked on a record in an external table, I had to display a popup for that feature. This is how I solved the problem.

1. When drawing the map, I saved the layer source, the list of features in a global variable.
2. When user clicks on the record in the table, I get the ID of the record.
3. Get the feature - layerSource.getFeatureById (id)
4. Draw the popup. (don't think you are interested in this step)

If you have to set the style, I think you will need to remove the old Vector layer from the map, and redraw the layer again. For the style, you will need to use a function that will return a different style for the selected feature.

Comment: My problem is the how can i make the manual 'select' event to pass thorught the ol.interaction.select style. I have the feature, i have the interaction, i have the selection style function (given to the interaction) but i dont kow how to combine them to make programatically selection  as it as from map. I have this code : 
`selectControl.getFeatures().push(featureToSelect);
selectControl.dispatchEvent({
   type: 'select',
   selected: [featureToSelect],
   deselected: [],
});` but my selection style doesn't apply. It applies the default selection style.